# How to set radio button selected from angular controller

Tags: angularjs

I am stuck to very simple thing. I am creating readion buttons by using ng-repeat. I want to set radio button selected if some value from billing.defaultBilling is true. Please help to resolve this.
My code is as follows.

```
 <li ng-repeat= "billing in CCInfoArray">
    <div class="pull-left">
        <div class="textLeft mSans500 font16">
           <input type="radio"><span class="ng-binding">CreditCard ending with {{ billing.displayCC }}  {{ billing.defaultBilling}} </span>
        </div> 
   </div>
</li>
```

My controller code is `factory.BillingInfo()
    .success(function (billingInfo) {
         for(var i = 0; i< billingInfo.list.length; i++){
        $scope.CCInfoArray.push({
            "billingIde":billingInfo.list[i].billingId,
                "defaultBilling":billingInfo.list[i].defaultBilling
            });
        }`

Its easy with jquery but how to do this with angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case it would be something like this:

```
<li ng-repeat= "billing in CCInfoArray">
    <div class="pull-left">
        <div class="textLeft mSans500 font16">
           <input type="radio" ng-model="billing.defaultBilling" value="true"><span class="ng-binding">CreditCard ending with {{ billing.displayCC }}  {{ billing.defaultBilling}} </span>
        </div> 
   </div>
</li>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Comment: I amde a working plnkr for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/dBM9vS7TAzFyvt14jNlz?p=preview what value is defaultBilling? it's Boolean: true or string 'true'?

Comment: It's same for my plunker example, check it carefully